# How to use JSON.NET to serialize a list of POCO's as a list of strings, to reduce size?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I've got a simple POCO like this:

```
    public class Edit { ... }

    public class CharInsert : Edit
    {
        public int ParagraphIndex { get; set; }
        public int CharacterIndex { get; set; }
        public char Character { get; set; }
    }
```

which serializes in JSON like this (note that I'm recording the object type, because of the inheritance):

```
 {
    "$type": "MyNamespace.CharInsert, MyAssembly",
    "paragraphIndex": 7,
    "characterIndex": 15,
    "character": "e"
  }
```

But this takes up a HUGE amount of space for a fairly little amount of data. And I have a LOT of them, so I need to be more compact about it.

I made a custom `JsonConverter` so that it will instead serialize as this:

```
  "CharInsert|7|15|e"
```

and when I persist a **list** of these, I get:

```
[
  "CharInsert|7|12|Z",
  "CharInsert|7|13|w",
  "CharInsert|7|14|i",
  "CharInsert|7|15|e",
]
```

But when I try to **deserialize** this list, I get the error:

> 'Error converting value "CharInsert|7|12|Z" to type 'MyNamespace.Edit'

I suppose this is because the actual object is a subclass of the Edit type and it doesn't know which one because it doesn't know how to parse the string. How can I implement this so it can parse the string, resolve the typename contained therein, and then create the needed object type?

Comment: Kinda like List<custObject> that get "to Csv"-ed then wrap it in a Json object that has a property telling you what Csv configuration should be used for deserialisation?

Comment: Why not use BSON or some other more lightweight format than JSON?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to custom converters, consider using `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "")]` to shorten the json property names, which should decrease space and you dont have to worry about custom converters.

```
    public class CharInsert : Edit
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "p")]
        public int ParagraphIndex { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "i")]
        public int CharacterIndex { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "c")]
        public char Character { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. The issue is that, without type information in the serialized string (`"CharInsert|7|15|e"`), the deserializer doesn't know what derived class to call.

So I made a `JsonConverter` for the base `Edit` type that knows how to parse the string and create and return and object from that string:

```
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            //get the persisted value
            var s = reader.Value?.ToString();

            var fields = s.Split('|');
            var typeName = ...get the type name from the field

            var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

            //create an object from the remaining fields using the ctor(string value) that
            //each subclass must have
            return System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { fields.Skip(1).ToJoinedString("|") });
        }
```

Comment: I would seriously consider changing this approach, the current implementation is very fragile and error prone. Imagine that the fields in the object have changed between serialization and deserialization?

Comment: This isn't because of the serializer not knowing the type, but rather because `"CharInsert|7|15|e"` isn't a valid JSON object. The default deserializer can't fill the Property in your `CharInsert` objects from non JSON

Comment: I don't know why you are even using JSON.Net if you're not using JSON.

Comment: @DmitriTsoy: change to what? Changing the fields tends to break things even in conventional serialization.

Comment: @MindSwipe: the data type is a List<T>, I just want to serialize T as a string a shown, to save about 90% of the space, while still using JSON as the file format.

Comment: @DavidG: I am using JSON. This is one element of many, but one that gets very large, so I wanted to optimize for size just here, while using JSON for the overall format.

Comment: Yes, but why use JSON? It's a terrible format for file sizes. Just use binary serialisation.

Comment: @DavidG: Agreed, but they're great for human accessibility and debugging. Binary formats are horrible for figuring out what went wrong, and one bad byte destroys the file.